# Is there any limitation for amount of tuples in CQL3 SELECT...IN clause?

Tags: select, cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-2.0

Cassandra CQL3 `SELECT` statement allows using `IN` tuples like in

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE userid='john doe' AND (blog_title, posted_at)
IN (('John''s Blog', '2012-01-01), ('Extreme Chess', '2014-06-01'))
```

as seen from CQ3 spec: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt

Is there limitation for amount of tuples can be used in SELECT's IN clause? What is the maximum?

Answer (score 8):

Rebecca Mills of DataStax provides a definite limit on the number of keys allowed in an `IN` statement ([Things you should be doing when using Cassandra drivers](https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/246/) - point #22):

> ...specifically the limit on the number of keys in
>   an IN statement, the most you can have is 65535. But practically
>   speaking you should only be using small numbers of keys in INs, just
>   for performance reasons.

I assume that limit would also apply to the number of tuples that you could specify as well.  Honestly though, I wouldn't try to top that out.  If you sent it a large number, it wouldn't perform well at all.  The [CQL documentation on the SELECT CLAUSE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) warns users about this:

> **When not to use IN**
>
> The recommendations about when not to use an index apply to using IN
>   in the WHERE clause. Under most conditions, using IN in the WHERE
>   clause is not recommended. Using IN can degrade performance because
>   usually many nodes must be queried. For example, in a single, local
>   data center cluster with 30 nodes, a replication factor of 3, and a
>   consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM, a single key query goes out to two
>   nodes, but if the query uses the IN condition, the number of nodes
>   being queried are most likely even higher, up to 20 nodes depending on
>   where the keys fall in the token range.

Suffice to say that while the maximum number of tuples you *could* pass is a matter of mathematics, the number of tuples you *should* pass will depend on your cluster configuration, JVM implementation, and a little bit of common sense.